# Multiple cells within a cell in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

Is it possible to have multiple (CheckBox or TextBox) cells inside a cell in a DataGridView?

If so, how would you begin to do this?

If this is not possible, what's the best way to separate multiple sections of text within one cell?

Comment: at least 1 way is create a usercontrol with a textbox with other control like another textbox and then add it,take a look at this article in msdn - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell

Comment: @terrybozzio That's great idea. Go ahead and post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least 1 way is create a usercontrol with a textbox with other control like another textbox and then add it,take a look at this article in msdn - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell
Here you go glimpse,glad i could help.